# show create view definition

Tags: mysql

When I do "Show create view viewName" it does the display the correctly formatted text.

I will like to know if there is any way to format it exactly like "show create table tblName"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.

MySQL stores the view definition in canonical form, so that's what it gives you when you run `show create view`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-create-view.html