# Definition of a view in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Is there any query/SQL Statement to see definition of a `view` in `DB2`?

I tried the following and it is resulting in an error as shown below

```
  SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.VIEWS
```

[image]

**REFERENCE**:

1. [show create view definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341072/show-create-view-definition)
2. [How to view DB2 Table structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973186/how-to-view-db2-table-structure)

**VERSION**:

Test results based on [How to check db2 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821795/how-to-check-db2-version) are listed below (for version)

[image]

---

Comment: Which DB2 version and type (LUW or Host)?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821795/how-to-check-db2-version

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. The question is updated with `Version` information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have admin permissions to the database, you can use the `db2look` utility:

```
db2look.exe -i your_userid -w your_password -d your_database -e -t your_table
```

Change the variables that start with `your_`.

If that doesn't work for you, you should be able to do:

```
SELECT TEXT
FROM SYSIBM.SYSVIEWS
```

If your platform (I can't see your picture for some reason) is the Mainframe DB2 (z/OS), then be aware that the catalog view will only show a part of the definition, if it's very long, it'll be cut off (on mine, z/OS v9.1, it only shows the first 1500 characters of the definition).

Comment: Thanks. SysIBM Helped -- SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSVIEWS  WHERE NAME LIKE '%V1_NID%' AND CREATOR  = 'ABASC'

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, cast(text as varchar(8000))
from SYSIBM.SYSVIEWS
where name='your table name'
```

In statement is the view-definition...

Comment: do try to add some details to support your answer. see [answer]

Answer (score 0):

```
      select name, cast(text as varchar(10000))
      from SYSIBM.SYSVIEWS
      where name='YourVIEW'
```